# how to know if a word has repeated letters in python?

Tags: python

I'm working on processing words in python and I want to see if a string has 3 or more occurances of the same letter back to back .Is there a better way to do that other than a nested for loop ? example: "helllooooo"

Comment: is it consecutive check ?

Comment: Are you looking for repetition of a particular character or **any** character that repeats 3 or more times consecutively. Do you just need a True/False response?

Answer (score 5):

As another option, looping once but checking the next two letters ahead will work, and the loop is smaller since you don't have to check the last two characters AND you can break as soon as you find a hit:

```
for i in range(0, len(instring)-2):
    if (instring[i] == instring[i+1] == instring[i+2]):
        print(f"{instring[i]} occurs three or more times.")
        break
```

Optionally, if you need to know the value or position in the string where these sequences appear, you could generate a list that holds the index of the letter that start a three-in-a-row sequence:

```
print([[i,c] for i,c in enumerate(instring) if i < len(instring)-2 and (c == instring[i+1] == instring[i+2])])
```

This will generate a list of lists with the letter and the position in the word where sequence of 3 is found.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a nested loop - just keep track of the last character you saw and use a counter

```
def atleast3(s):
    count = 0
    last = None
    for c in s:
        if c == last:
            count += 1
            if count >= 3:
                return True
        else:
            count = 1
        last = c
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

One loop can work

```
string = 'hellooo'
res = ''
prev_item = ''
for item in string:
    if item == prev_item:
        res += '1'
    else:
        res += '0'
    prev_item = item

print(res) #'0001011'
   
if '11' in res:
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way (there usually is) but if you're looking for **any** character that repeats at least *n* times consecutively in a string then:

```
def has_repeats(s, n=3):
    for i in range(len(s)-n+1):
        if (a := s[i:i+n]).count(a[0]) == n:
            return True
    return False

print(has_repeats('helllooooo'))
```

**Output:**

```
True
```

The default value for *n* is 3. You could override this if needed to any number.

If you're looking specifically for a sequence of 3 characters then this might be faster:

```
def has_3_repeats(s):
    for t in zip(s, s[1:], s[2:]):
        if t.count(t[0]) == 3:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool for that. `itertools.groupby` will group by each change in a primary key (in this case, the next letter in the word). Its second term is an iterator that will emit like valued items (consecutive letters).

```
>>> import itertools
>>> for letter, seq in itertools.groupby("hellloooooooo"):
...     sz = len(list(seq))
...     if sz >= 3:
...             print(letter, sz)
... 
l 3
o 8
```

You could break out of the loop early if you only care about finding the first sequence, as in

```
for _, seq in itertools.groupby("hellloooooooo"):
    if len(list(seq)) >= 3:
        has_3 = True
        break
else:
    has_3 = False
```

Comment: No disputing the functional correctness of this. Other ideas facilitate an 'early detection' whereas *groupby()* must parse the entire string. Is this therefore potentially inefficient ?

Comment: @LancelotduLac - I'm not sure what the intent of the original question is. I'll update with something that exits early.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done pretty succinctly with regular expressions

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r"((?P<s>[a-zA-Z0-9])(?P=s){2,})", "hellllooooooo")
[('llll', 'l'), ('ooooooo', 'o')]
```

Comment: As with the groupby solution this requires the entire string to be parsed whereas other answers suggest an 'early detection'. Does that raise a potential performance issue?

Comment: @LancelotduLac This example gets all the occurrences. You could use `re.search` to just find the first occurrence and skip parsing the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Idea is to `shift` the word and compare,

First, create a Pandas Series from the given word

```py
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(list(w))
```

```
print(s)

0    h
1    e
2    l
3    l
4    l
5    o
6    o
7    o
8    o
9    o
dtype: object
```

Then you can group by and `shift` the Series to find continuous char

```py
m = s.groupby(s).filter(lambda g: g.eq(g.shift().bfill()).sum() >= 3)
```

```
print(m)

2    l
3    l
4    l
5    o
6    o
7    o
8    o
9    o
dtype: object
```

If you want to determine the repeated char and repeated times

```py
print(m.value_counts())

o    5
l    3
dtype: int64
```

If you want to find the location of repeated chars

```py
i = m.groupby(m).apply(lambda g: g.iloc[[0, -1]].index.tolist()).to_dict()
```

```
print(i)

{'l': [2, 4], 'o': [5, 9]}
```

Answer (score -1):

here's a function I've made, it should return `True` if the word has repeated letters, `False` if it doesn't.

```py
def repeated_letters(word:str):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(word) -1):
        if word[i] == word[i+1]:
            count += 1
            if count == 2:
                return True
        else:
            count = 0
    return False
```

Comment: Firstly the question is to detect 3 same letters in a row, your code is ignoring position. Secondly it should be ```count[i]``` not ```count[s]```,  please revise

Comment: Ok i will revise